# Nextjs with Nodejs Thread Pool

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm using nextJS with NodeJS and want to enable child processes or workers. The code provided by nextjs themselves works completely fine.

**The code provided by NextJS that I'm talking about:* [NextJS with NodeJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)
**The other site I followed:* [NextJS with Express](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-server-rendered-react-app-next-express/)

```js
server.listen(8080, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${8080}`);
});
```

I tried replacing the above code with this:

```js
//if the cluster is master
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numCpu; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  //if worker dies or is killed
  cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  server.listen(8080, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${8080}`);
  });
}
```

But it gives an error

```js
info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\restro\.env
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 535 ms (143 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 502 ms (143 modules)
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Gp\Desktop\restro\.next\trace'
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Gp\\Desktop\\restro\\.next\\trace'
}
```

Simply the code looks like this

```js
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.all("*", (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    // server.listen(port, (err) => {
    //   if (err) throw err;
    //   console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    // });

    //if the cluster is master
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
      for (let i = 0; i < numCpu; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
      }

      //if worker dies or is killed
      cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
        cluster.fork();
      });
    } else {
      server.listen(8080, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${8080}`);
      });
    }
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it if you are searching for the same thing. :)

```js
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const cluster = require("cluster");
const os = require("os");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

//if the cluster is master
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numCpu; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  //if worker dies or is killed
  cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  app
    .prepare()
    .then(() => {
      const server = express();

      server.all("*", (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
      });

      server.listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`, process.pid);
      });

    })
    .catch((ex) => {
      console.error(ex.stack);
      process.exit(1);
    });
  }
```